# GLEW OpenGL Access violation when using glGenVertexArrays

Tags: opengl, sdl, glew

**In my case.. This problem was fixed by updating the driver of the graphics card.**

---

I have searched and found people with the same problem on stackoverflow and the internet. However, the answers aren't solving my problem.

I am using SDL2 and GLEW. When I run the application, I receive an ''Access violation'' error when this function is executed:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
```

My code:

```
bool Game::initSDL(char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, int flags) {
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)>=0) {
    Uint32 flags = SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN|SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL;
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION,4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    mainWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);
    mainGLContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mainWindow);

    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));

    }
    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID); 
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

} else {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: try setting VertexArrayID to 0 first GLuint VertexArrayID = 0;

Comment: @jamolnng: that is a pointless operation

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
Unfortunately, it still doesn't work (same error).

Comment: @user3125591: check if you actually got a 3.x context, and that ` glGenVertexArrays` is actually a non-`NULL` pointer.

Comment: @derhass Worth a shot, sometimes it is the simplest thing, especially if something is not initialized, even if it is an integer.

Comment: I tried calling wglGetCurrentContext() and it returns:
00020000. I don't understand what this means and I'm looking this up at the moment.

Comment: I believe I'm using an old version of OpenGL (2.1) rather than the newest.. I will be updating my drivers asap.

Comment: @user3125591: I don't know SDL well enough, but maybe you have to explicitely use `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent()` after you created the window and the context to actually make it current.

Comment: @user3125591: OTOH, `glewInit` should fail if without a valid context.

Comment: @user3125591: Vertex Array Objects do not exist in OpenGL 2.1. You ***might*** have access to them in the form of an [extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_array_object.txt), but the proper function would be `glGenVertexArraysARB (...)` (this was the original function name before the extension was promoted to core unless you are using `GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object`). Do not call functions that are not core unconditionally, GLEW has macros you can use to check whether a particular extension (**`GL_ARB_vertex_array_object`** in this case) is supported.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. After updating my graphics card drivers, it seems that everything (including the glGenVertexArrays function) is working! :D 
Now this may sound weird, but I regret updating my drivers (the temperature of my graphics card seems a little hot now). 
For development purposes, I assume having installed the latest drivers is better than using a workaround?

Comment: There is no work-around for a driver that is missing functionality your application requires. Of course you can write multiple code paths, but if you are doing this simply to support older **drivers** and not older generations of **hardware**, you are in for a world of hurt. You would have to write code paths all the way back to OpenGL 1.1, because any installation of Windows that does not have an IHV supplied driver (basically what you get by going directly to nvidia.com or amd.com) does not include hardware OpenGL drivers and will limit you to OpenGL 1.1 (regardless how new the GPU is).

Comment: Ok, very clear. Thank you!
I ended up uninstalling the driver (it causes high temps)
But I will download another one asap that supports OpenGL 3.x.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 6):

try adding this, glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;, before glewInit().

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
glewInit();
```

Comment: Same result unfortunately.

Comment: try commenting out the two SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_*, *) methods and see what happens

Comment: I just had the same problem as user3125591 and I solved it using the glewExperimental = GL_TRUE fix. Thanks ! I was following the tutorial over at http://openglbook.com/chapter-2-vertices-and-shapes.html where I had the issue.

Comment: I can only second this, I had EXACTLY the same issue and that solved it for me.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, and you're using GLFW, make sure you call glewInit _after_ glfwInit.